# How to parse arguments in routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I tried to define a route for application overview and application details. Applications are listed in a table in overview page. When user clicks on an application row, it will be redirect to detail page (e.g. `/app/1`)

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute', 'appsOverviewCtrl', 'appDetailCtrl'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/apps', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/overview.html',
        controller: 'appsOverviewCtrl'
    }).when('/app/:appId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html',
        controller: 'appDetailCtrl'
    });
})
```

Now in detail page, I will try to extract the `appId`. I googled a bit, there is a way of using Angular service. But I believe there is some other more straightforward ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you can use `$routeParams`

```
function controllerName($scope, $routeParams)
{
  $scope.value = $routeParams.appId;
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes. How could I have missed this thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Example from [AngularJS Phonecat tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)

Is this not working for you?

```
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams) {
     $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;
  }]);
```

In your case it would be `$routeParams.appId`. Remember to include `$routeParams` in your controller.

However `['$scope', '$routeParams'` is not required. Just nice to have if you're minifying.

Comment: Thanks you. By the way, I think the code `['$scope', '$routeParams'` is not necessary. Even I write `phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', function(`, it still works.

Comment: Yea, your are right. However, correct me if I'm wrong, but I think `['$scope', '$routeParams'` is needed when uglifying. Just to clearify. If I'm wrong please correct me, so I can edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

The appId will be available in $route.current.params or in $routeParams if you inject it in your controller.